# Tradução incompleta na tela de sinalização

Tags: bug, tradução

Existem alguns trechos na tela de sinalização que estão sem tradução.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu ia perguntar aqui no meta justamente isso. Isso já foi traduzido há um tempo, o que será que aconteceu?

Comment: Não vi no site principal, mas reproduzi aqui no meta. Tanto versão mobile quanto versão completa